# Buffer is too small when doing strcpy_s

Tags: c, windows, windows-7-x64, visual-studio-2010

Any idea why my code snippet is throwing exception `"Buffer is too small"` when using strcpy_s though no problem if I do strcpy or CopyMemory?

```
WindowClass(LPCTSTR pszClassName, WNDPROC pfnWndProc) : m_pszClassName(0)
{
    ...

    if( RegisterClass(&wc) )
    {
        size_t cbClassName = strlen(pszClassName);
        m_pszClassName = (LPTSTR)LocalAlloc(LPTR, cbClassName + 1);

        if( m_pszClassName )
        {
            //strcpy(m_pszClassName, pszClassName);
            strcpy_s(m_pszClassName, cbClassName, pszClassName);
            //CopyMemory(m_pszClassName, pszClassName, cbClassName);
        }
        else
        {
            UnregisterClass(pszClassName, hinst);
        }
    }
}
```

Target is Win7x64 on VS2012 without UNICODE.

Comment: What is `m_pszClassName` defined as ?

Comment: You need to account for the space for the null-char terminator in passing the size parameter. I.e. it needs to be the same as your allocation size: `cbClassName + 1`. The API is detecting there isn't space for the string plus the null-char, and therefore asserting. From the MS docs on `strcpy_s` : "The destination string must be large enough to hold the source string, **including the terminating null character**."

Comment: @WhozCraig: Why not make this an answer?

Comment: @alk it wasn't quite so.. wordy, when I first started typing it (in fact, it was just "pass cbClasName+1", got a little out of control =P)

Comment: @PaulR LPTSTR  m_pszClassName;

Comment: @WhozCraig nice, made a slight change, "size_t cbClassName = strlen(pszClassName) + 1;" to be on safe side. So now passing "cbClassName" includes the extra space for terminating null character.